# Does installing a silencer affect damage?

Tags: wolfenstein-2009

Does installing a silencer lower damage, as it often does in games?

[image: store screenshot]

Comment: No i think its just slows the bullet drop on the weapon.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in [the wiki](http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Wolfenstein_(2009)) says anything about damage reduction or anything like it. It seems like it is only a sound modificator.

Never played Wolfenstein, but it might also be useful to use without the silencer to attract ennemies to a particular spot.